# how to change ipv6 to ipv4?

Tags: sockets, apache-storm

i've problem with change ipv6 to ipv4 when i used this command

```
lsof -i :6702
```

got this

```
java 3143 st 71u IPv6 12097 0t0 TCP *:6702 (LISTEN)
```

as you can see it using `ipv6` and i want to change it to `ipv4`

i used the

```
supervisor.childopts: "-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"
```

in storm.yaml

summary in storm ui read the change but when i used

lsof -i :6702 didn't read it ! still using ipv6 !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error disappered by adding this property

```
 -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

to nimbus and supervisor and worker in storm.yaml

Answer (score 1):

If 6702 is a worker, perhaps try to add -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true to worker.childopts as well?

It looks like you are on a dual stack node. The v6 socket should accept incoming v4 connections transparently. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: i'm facing problem with supervisor after accepted some data it stopped then got still hasn't start !! by executing the command that launch between supervisor and worker got error to bind 0.0.0.0/6702 then i checked the port by the above command and got what i posted 6702 is port for supervisor

Comment: If the connect is succeeding your problem is not the socket. Try connecting with `telnet 127.0.0.1 6702` to see if it works.

Comment: It looks like you are running on linux (lsof is available). Try running `telnet 127.0.0.1 6702`. If it says connected, then IPv4 connections to that socket are fine. That rules out any IPv6 problems.

Comment: i got that Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.

Comment: Your problem is clearly not IPv6 related. Is everything running on one machine?

Comment: yes i changed nimbus and worker and supervisor with this property  -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true ipv6 changed to ipv4 , but still i have another error in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33621867/error-in-binding-port-and-its-free

Comment: can you help in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33621867/error-in-binding-port-and-its-free